# Build operations are disabled:'project.xcworkspace' has changed and is reloading

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I got this message, which is as follows.

[image: Build operations alert]

Then again I tried to rebuild it, which lead me to this alert message.
[image]

Now if I select Xcode Version, it starts throwing error which is related to the dependency of the external libraries I have added. Any suggestion.
[image]

Comment: You should launch the RCSClient.xcworkspace in the folder, not RCSClient.xcodeproj

Comment: I don't think xcworkspace vs xcodeproj is the issue here. Certainly isn't the case for me when this occurs as I definitely have the xcworkspace open.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I have the exact same issue with Xcode 7.3.

Restarting the IDE helps.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue with Xcode 9.3 and solution mentioned by @sssliver didn’t worked.

[image: Screenshot added]

Below is solution that worked :

1. `Quit Xcode (cmd + Q)` and reopen project
2. `Delete derived data` content.
3. `Clean project (cmd + shift + K)`
4. `Build project (cmd + B)`

Answer (score 4):

**This error occurs usually when you open a project in 2 Xcode versions or
When project is opened in one Xcode and you are trying to open that in other Xcode versions.**

**Here are the steps to follow:-**

1. Quit both Xcode by (cmd + Q)
2. Open Xcode

**If problem still exists then**

3. Clean build folder
4. Build project
5. Run

Answer (score 3):

On Xcode 11 when I changed my app folder location, I got this error and thats was because Swift Package Manager was redownloading my project libraries, once it finished downloading, it worked again...

Answer (score 2):

Below solution worked for me:

Quit Xcode (cmd + Q) and reopen project
Delete derived data content.
Clean project (cmd + shift + K)
Build project (cmd + B)

Answer (score 1):

Below is solution that worked for me:

Quit Xcode (cmd + Q) and reopen project

Delete derived data content.

Clean project (cmd + shift + K)

Restart Mac

Build project (cmd + B)